# Best way to use PHP to run another remote php script

Tags: php

I am wanting to create a web-based cronjob system for my userbase, and would need to know the best way to open a php script on a remote server, and ensure the script runs (could take 3 minutes), and use the least ammount of resources on my own side.

There is the possibility of having hundreds of connections open at one time.

Any advice on how I should go about doing this?

Thanks allot,
Hudson

Comment: Perhaps this previous question could be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. it depends on what exactly do you need. I've used popen() for creating several sub-processes in cronjob transferring 100k records and it proved to be fine. Your needs could satisfy load ballancer called Gearman. It can handle requests asynchronously. Look at event-driven approach. You can see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516960/anatomy-of-a-distributed-system-in-php/1517761#1517761) on stackoverflow. This solution can scale.