# Architectural design for data consistency on distributed analytic system

Tags: sql-server, architecture, message-queue, distributed, distributed-caching

I am refactoring an Analytic system that will do a lot of calculation, and I need some ideas on possible architectural designs to a data consistency issue I am facing.

**Current Architecture**

I have a queue based system, in which different requesting applications create messages that are eventually consumed by workers.

Each "*Requesting App*" breaks down a large calculation into smaller pieces that will be sent to the queue and processed by the *workers*.

When all the pieces are finished, the originating *"Requesting app"* will consolidate the results.

Also, the *workers* consume information from a centralized database (SQL Server) in order to process the requests (*Important: the workers do not change any data on the database, only consume it*).

[image: Current Architecture]

**Problem**

Ok. So far, so good. The problem arises when we include a web service that updates the information on the database. This can happen at any time, but it is critical that each "large calculation" originated from the same "Requesting App" sees the same data on the database.

For Example:

1. App *A* generates messages A1 and A2, sending it to queue
2. Worker *W1* picks up message A1 for processing.
3. The web server updates the database, changing from state *S0* to *S1*.
4. Worker *W2* picks up message A2 for processing

I just can´t have worker W2 using state S1 of the database. for the whole calculation to be consistent it should use the previous S0 state.

**Thoughts**

1. A **lock pattern** to prevent the web server from changing the database while there is a worker consuming information from it.

   - **cons**: The lock might be on for a long time, since the calculation form different "Request Apps" might overlap (A1, B1, A2, B2, C1, B3, etc.).
2. Create **new layer** between the database and the workers (a server that controls db caching by req. app)

   - **cons**: Adding another layer might impose significant overhead (maybe?), and it is a lot of work, since I will have to rewrite the persistence of the workers (a lot of code).

I am pending to the second solution, but not very confident about it.

Any brilliant ideas ? Am I designing it wrong, or missing something ?

OBS:

- This is a HUGE 2-tier legacy system (in C#) that we are trying to
  evolve into a more scalable solution with as minimal effort as
  possible.
- Each worker is potentially running on different servers.

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like map/reduce to me.  Why would you write such a thing yourself?  I'd just use Hadoop.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a HUGE 2-tier legacy system (in C#) that we are trying to evolve into a more scalable solution with as minimal effort as possible. I believe changing everything to hadoop will be a massive task.

Comment: More massive than writing, debugging, and maintaining what Hadoop already does?  I would be sure before committing.

Comment: I agree with @duffymo. You're going to spend the rest of your lives trying to make this to work, discovering that eventual consistency is the best you can hope for, and having to write manual reconciliation procedures to deal with node failure. You're better off suggesting a full rewrite in a language designed for this, perhaps ERLang, with hadoop.

Comment: I am not very familiar w/ Hadoop, so help me out. This system has over 1 Million lines of code, and already does the segregation/calculation/aggregation (Map/Reduce), but it does In-Memory (single server). It also has a lot of intelligence on the SQL Server (stored-procedures, functions, etc.). Now I need it to scale-out, and I´ve migrated to this queue architecture easily w/ few weeks of development. Except for the database concurrency issues. Do you think Hadoop can help in my case ? if so, please point me in the right direction. (I can´t rewrite my whole application)

Comment: I'm not clear on how Hadoop solves this problem.  Hadoop might be one (of many possible) tools used to implement solution #2, but it certainly doesn't solve the problem out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for the help.

Since I believe this is problem might be usual in other scenarios, I would like to share the solution we chose.

Thinking more thoroughly about the problem, I understood it for what it really is.

- I needed some sort of session control for each job
- There was a cache in-process that served as a session control for each job

Now the calculation has evolved to be distributed, I just needed to evolve my cache to be distributed as well.

In order to do that, we chose to use an In-Memory Database (hash-value), deployed as a separate server. (in this case [Redis](http://redis.io/)).

Now every time I start a job, I create a ID for the job and pass it to their messages

When each worker wants some information from the database, it would:

1. Look for the data in Redis (with the job ID)
2. If the data is in Redis, use the data
3. If it is not, load it from SQL, and save it in redis (with the job ID).

At the end of the job, I clear all hashes associated with the job ID.

Answer (score 1):

Can you version your DB ?

Lets say the requesting application stamps the start of the calculation with ct1. Now every message this calculation generates is stamped with the same timestamp.

And also each DB update stamps the DB state with the time of the update. So state S0 is on time t0, state S1 on t1 etc.

Now when a worker gets a message it needs to get the DB state where the update time is the largest that is smaller or equal to the message time. In your example, if A1 and A2 are stamped with ct1, and t1 > ct1, both workers will retrieve S0 and not S1.

This means of course that you need to hold several versions in your DB. You can clean those versions after a certain time if you know that your computations must have finished after some time window.

Comment: You have a good point. I could prepare every table to allow versioning, although I would need to rewrite the whole schema. Are you aware of any feature in Sql Server that would do that automatically or at least make it easier ?

Comment: Not really. But adding timestamp rows to your DB schema usually shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I like option 2, especially if the amount of data needed for the full set of calculations isn't unreasonably large.  I assume there is a way to correlate (via id) calculations that belong to the same overall job?

When the first message of a set of calculations comes in, the worker that picks it up queries the database and for all the data necessary to do all calculations and creates a temporary data store.  What this data store would look like would depend on a lot of factors (size, structure, etc.), but it could be a blob/document, a set of data in a relational schema (isolated by correlationId), an entry in an enterprise cache, etc.

You'd need to be careful of the case when Worker 1 and Worker 2 are both working on the same set of calculations, since only one of them should create the data store, and both would need to wait until the store is fully populated before proceeding.

Comment: I can correlate the the calculations to the same overall job. I can generate an ID and set it to all the calculations. But discovering all the data that the job will need is a very complex task for me. I was considering adding a new server to the architecture that all workers will access instead of the database. this server will mantain a cache of the results from the database by job ID. what do you think ?

Comment: Aren't you back to the original problem, then?  Or does each calculation in the sequence only rely on the results of the previous calculation?

Comment: each calculation is independent from each other´s result, they only depend on data from the database. This "server" would be unique, acting as a facade for all connections to the database, so that it can manage everyone´s cache in-memory. Not very confident about it though.

Comment: Hmm, still not clear on how this would solve the problem.  Can't the database still change between messages A1 and A2?  I think you need to do something akin to taking a snapshot of the database when the first message arrives.